# Porque mi vista no reconoce mi funcion?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-7

Buenas estoy teniendo un problema con javascript y laravel en mi vista. Estoy incluyendo un script dentro de una vista blade pero obtengo el siguiente error: "TypeError: discount is not a function".

Lo raro es que cree un archivo index.html por fuera de mi proyecto y funcionaba correctamente pero por algun motivo cuando lo hago en el proyecto de laravel no funciona.

Les muestro mi vista con el html y el script:

```
@extends('backend.layouts.master')
@section('content')
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper bg-white">
    <!--Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm 6">
                    <h1 class="m-0 text-white"></h1>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Detalle Presupuestos</li>
                    </ol>
                </div><!-- /.col-->
             </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <section class="content">
     <div class="container-fluid">
     <!-- Main Row -->
         <div class="row">
        <!-- Left Col -->
        <section class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Custom Tabs -->
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header text-white"  style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);">
                    <h3 class="font-weight-lighter">Agregar Detalle de Presupuesto
                        <a href="{{ route('presupuestos-productos.view') }}" class="btn bg-white float-right btn-sm">
                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                            Detalles
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                </div><!-- /.Card Header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('presupuestos-productos.store') }}" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                    <div class="form-row">
                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="presupuesto_id">Presupuesto</label>
                            <select name="presupuesto_id" class="form-control">
                              <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                              @foreach ($presupuestos as $presupuesto)
                              <option value="{{ $presupuesto->id }}">{{ $presupuesto->id }}</option>
                              @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="product_id">Producto</label>
                            <select name="product_id" class="form-control">
                              <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                              @foreach ($products as $product)
                              <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->id }}</option>
                              @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        
                        
                       
                    
                        

                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <label for="sale_price">Precio de Venta</label>
                            <input type="number"  pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="00.01" name="sale_price" class="form-control" id="saleP" onkeyup="discount()" onchange="discount();" >
                        </div>



                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="discount_percentage">Porcentaje de descuento (%)</label>
                            <input type="number" name="discount_percentage" class="form-control" id="discountP" onkeyup="discount();" onchange="discount();">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="discount">Descuento</label>
                            <input type="number" name="discount" placeholder="discount" id="discountAmount" class="form-control"  >
                        </div>

                        

                        


                       

                      

                    

                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input type="submit" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-md text-white" style="background:#030335e8">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
                </div><!-- /.card-body-->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </section>
        <!-- right col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row (main row) -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->


<script>


    function discount(){
        const price = document.getElementById('saleP').value;
        const percentage = document.getElementById('discountP').value;
        const discount = (price* percentage)/100
        document.getElementById('discountAmount').value = discount; 
    }

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (){
    $('#myForm').validate({
      rules:{
        category_id: {
            required: true,
        },
        ptype_id: {
            required: true,
        },
        model: {
            required: true,
        },
        brand: {
            required: true,
        },
      },
      messages: {

          category_id: {
              required: "Debe ingresar una categoria",
          },
          ptype_id: {
              required: "Debe ingresar tipo de producto",
          },
          model: {
              required: "Debe ingresar un modelo",
          },
          brand: {
              required: "Debe ingresar una marca",
          },
          brand: {
              required: "Debe ingresar una marca",
          }
      },
      errorElement: 'span',
      errorPlacement: function(error, element){
        error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
        element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
      },
      highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass){
        $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
      },
      unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass){
        $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
      }
    });
  });


        
  

  </script>



@endsection
```

La funcion del primer script es lo que no funciona. El segundo script que es jQuery funciona correctamente. Nose porque en mi vista me devuelve que discount is not a function.

Comment: Que pasa si pones esa función dentro del $(document).ready?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ obtengo el mismo error. Por alguna razón mis vistas de laravel no reconocen mis scripts.

Comment: A mi me pasaba lo mismo y lo solucione creando en la plantilla un espacio con yield solo para el los script, por ejemplo en la plantilla backend.layouts.master debes crear una seccion para javascript y luego en cada pagina pones seccion('mis_script).......@endsecction

Comment: @Javier tenes un ejemplo para mostrarme? porque me cuesta entenderlo.

Comment: Revisa el código fuente en el navegador, ¿aparece ahí la función? Es probable que solo debas agregar el tipo de script, porque es la única diferencia entre las dos etiquetas y la que no funciona es la que no tiene `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: @Triby ya hice eso y tampoco funciona

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontré el problema.
El error es que estás usando una constante con el mismo nombre de la función, y eso no se puede, provoca un conflicto de nombres, intenta cambiar el nombre de la función discount o el de la constante discount